# Magento - Advanced Product Import

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento

I'm working on an auto parts supplier that currently uses a proprietary solution. In the database, they have a table for their products that references a "master table" for data. The master table's data is laid out below as an example...

```
Make ID        Make Name
1              Suzuki
2              Porsche
3              Hyundai
```

Then the file that I'm importing into Magento contains the integer for the Make. I'd like it to show the make name in Magento rather than the ID. In other words, if the import file has "1" for Make, I'd like this to import as "Suzuki".

How would I go about doing this? I think I'd do this with an INNER JOIN, but I'm not completely sure. I'm even more lost of where to get started in making it happen with Magento's import.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well where it says either `$this->getId()` or `$this->getMakeId()` or `$model->xY` you change it to `$this->getMakeName()` obviously since it is proprietary you should just ask them...

As for the join I have no idea what you want to join to, I am guessing you can just filter it